# Deployment in Travis-CI to GitHub Pages: which files will be uploaded?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, travis-ci

When I use deployment in Travis-CI to GitHub Pages, which files, or which kinds of files, will be uploaded to GitHub pages?

For example, here is from my .travis.yml, which does not tell which files will be uploaded.

```
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github_token: "$TOKEN"
  keep_history: true
  on:
    branch: main
```

Comment: If you look on the gh-pages branch, you can see - given that you don't set an explicit local_dir, everything in the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer after some search, which also corresponds to the comments above.

By default,  all files in the home directory of the travis ci server (including subdirectores) will be uploaded to GitHub pages.  If local_dir is specified in the "deploy" section of travis ci, then only files in local_dir will be uploaded.